# How to handle CORS error in JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: jquery, cors

I'm a newcomer and currently learning. While developing the web application I came across with the

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost/m/document/019286313eb7ce6_20210915125851.jpeg.webp' from origin 'https://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled

I did google and read few thing but I still can't figure it out how to fix this.

I don't have any access to the server because I'm only working with API. So I just want to know can jQuery fix the CORS problem or it has to be set on the backend ? I did install chrome extension for a quick fix for my testing development purpose but I just want to know if there is another method for this

this is what I have tried

```
 fetch('http://localhost/m/document/019286313eb7ce6_20210915125851.jpeg.webp', {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
              "accept": "application/json",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"
          }
        })
        .then(res => res.blob())
        .then(blob => {
            
            myBlob = blob;
            console.log(myBlob);
        });
```

Comment: Try running your frontend code from `http://localhost` instead? That is, non-https. Or if `http://localhost/m/document/019286313eb7ce6_20210915125851.jpeg.webp` (non-https) really is the URL you’re making the request to, and your frontend is at `http://localhost`, the try `https://localhost/m/document/019286313eb7ce6_20210915125851.jpeg.webp` (https) instead. Otherwise, if those really are your URLs, the reason you are running into that CORS error is that a request from an`https://localhost` URL to an `http://localhost` is a cross-origin request — because of he https-vs-http mismatch.

Comment: @sideshowbarker OMG you are the winner!!!! Thank you for stopping by. I have so much headaches for this error. I did not realize the `https-vs-http mismatch.` is an issue. thank you

Answer (score -1):

For a security reason on modern browser you depend on the server so the best way you can bypass this is to use a Proxy server that proxies your request and automatically enable CORS for your

Comment: proxy server such as herokuapp ? [link](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/issues/301)

Answer (score -1):

CORS error can be nightmare. CORS header i.e. Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a RESPONSE HEADER and you cannot set a response header at CLIENT. Its purpose is to protect server responses from unknown domains extended to disallow usage of APIs.
In your case as you don't have access to server. You have options

1. "To continue with the chrome extension temporarily allowing your development machine to access the API".
2. To change the header at SERVER to include your domain. (need server access)
3. Access the API independently and supply results to your app as file(JSON File).
4. Configure Proxy: You can define to forward any requests coming for the path /m to http://localhost/m at your frontend development server. Since your development server is the middleman communicating with your backend API, it can safely avoid CORS.

Comment: Can I know more about the option no 3 ? Meaning I have to change setting in my xampp ?

Comment: I removed that option realising your CORS problem is because you accessing http-localhost from https-localhost. Can you detail domains of front-end and api.